# Switch statement output - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a problem where I cannot seem to wrap my head around why the answer is as it is. The question is what the code snippet below will output when the value of a is 8.

```
var n = ""
switch(a) {
    case 8:
        n += "bra ";
    case 10:
        n = "jon";
    case 12:
        n += "ny";
}
console.log(n);
```

My first guess was "bra ", because since a=8 the input will match the first case statement and hence concat "bra " to n. The solution however states "jonny" as the answer.

Can someone please explain what am I missing here? I would be very thankful.
Please be aware that I am a js beginner, so I may have missed something trivial.

Comment: You're missing `break` for each and every case

Comment: Ahh, of course! I should have seen that. Thanks everyone for good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `switch` statement simply jumps to the corresponding `case` label. That's it.

Thus for `8` you get:

```
switch(a) {
```

`a` is `8`, so jump to `case 8`.

```
    case 8:
```

Hey, this is our stop. Continue execution here.

```
        n += "bra ";
```

Append `"bra "` to `n`.

```
    case 10:
```

Another label. Executing a label does nothing.

```
        n = "jon";
```

Set `n` to `"jon"`.

```
    case 12:
```

Another label. Keep going.

```
        n += "ny";
```

Append `"ny"` to `n`.

```
}
```

Now `n` is `"jonny"`.

If you want to stop execution inside a `switch`, you need an explicit `break;`:

```
switch(a) {
    case 8:
        n += "bra ";
        break;
    case 10:
        n = "jon";
        break;
    case 12:
        n += "ny";
        break;  // technically redundant; this is the end of the switch block
}
```

This is why you normally see a `break` after every `case` group of statements.

By the way, this behavior is called "fallthrough" and was inherited from C.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var n = "";
let a=8;
switch(a) {
    case 8:
        n += "bra ";
        break;
    case 10:
        n = "jon";
        break;
    case 12:
        n += "ny";
        break;
}
console.log(n);
```

For `switch` to works, you need `break` in every case as above. When it's without a break, the program will flow down all the way from case 8 to case 12, resulted in below sequence

```
//case 8:  n = ""+bra
//case 10: n = jon
//case 12: n = jon+ny
```

As a result, n at last equals to `jonny`

Comment: This isn't a "how to fix it" question, it a question on understanding the code.

Comment: @musefan: I see. I was scratching my head for having 3 upvotes in comments but downvotes on answer. Anyway thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Even more confusing are the upvotes on your answer... I guess a lot of people really don't read the questions anymore

Answer (score 0):

It is to note that, in JavaScript a break statement is required to prevent control to fall through to the subsequent cases.

```
var n = ""
switch(a) {
    case 8:
        n += "bra ";  //n = "" + "bra " = "bra "
        //no break statement here, control falls through to the next case        
    case 10:
        n = "jon";    //n = "jon"
        //no break statement here, control falls through to the next case
    case 12:
        n += "ny";    //n = "jon" + "ny" = "jonny"
}
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score -1):

Because there is no use of the `break` keyword, logic will effectively 'fall through' all switch branches starting at the one that meets the condition. ([Which you can read more about here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)).

So in your example, *all* cases will be processed. This is the same as doing:

```
n += "bra ";
n = "jon";
n += "ny";
```

To which the result is obviously: `"jonny"`

---

If you wanted to only process the switch statement that is selected, then you can add the `break` keyword like so:

```
switch(a) {
    case 8:
        n += "bra ";
        break;
    case 10:
        n = "jon";
        break;
    case 12:
        n += "ny";
        break;
}
```

Comment: If someone could explain the downvotes then that would be useful. Is there something wrong with my code/answer? As far as I can see, it is essentially the same as the accepted answer (which was posted *after* I posted mine)